# Application freezes when no data is being received via ZMQ

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, zeromq

I'm using the following code to receive the frame string.

```
private SubscriberSocket subSocket;
 void Start()
 {
     subSocket = new SubscriberSocket();

     subSocket.Connect("tcp://localhost:5555");
 }

 void Update()
 {
     string data = subSocket.ReceiveFrameString();

 }
```

The problem with this code is that the unity application freezes when no data is being received from the client. How can I stop the application from freezing when there isn't any data being received?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Methods like `ReceiveFrameString` will block indefinitely until a message is received. There are a few ways to handle this, and it may depend on the library you are using. Note that ZeroMq is a *protocol*, and the libraries for .net I know about are clrzmq and NetMq.

**Do the call on a background thread**. Launch a longRunning task that only receives messages. Once received you can deal with them on the worker thread, start another task, or put them on a queue for the main thread to deal with. I'm not 100% how the threading model in unity works.

**Add a timeout to the call**. There should be an overload that takes a value for how long to wait. You should be able to give a low value, or zero to not wait. Be aware that the number of messages that are buffered will probably be limited.

**Use async calls**. At least libraries like NetMq have [async receive calls](https://netmq.readthedocs.io/en/latest/async-await/) that should be possible to use to avoid blocking.